# No file or picture opening in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

Today, each and every file and photo I tried to open showed up the message `You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "File".` I can neither open or copy them. In properties section for each, it shows size, location, type unknown as well as permissions as unknown. What should I do?

```
drw------- 3 prashant prashant    4096 Jan 22 15:31 Desktop
drw------- 7 prashant prashant    4096 Jan 18 13:08 Documents
drw------- 7 prashant prashant    4096 Jan 22 02:32 Downloads
drw------- 2 prashant prashant    4096 Jan 11 12:03 dwhelper
-rw------- 1 prashant prashant    8445 Jan  9 08:18 examples.desktop
drw------- 2 prashant prashant    4096 Jan  9 08:20 Music
drw------- 3 prashant prashant    4096 Jan 20 18:22 Pictures
drw------- 2 prashant prashant    4096 Jan  9 08:20 Public
-rw------- 1 prashant prashant    1972 Jan 22 14:41 SoftEther-VPN-Server
-rw------- 1 prashant prashant 5301222 Jan 22 15:00 softether-vpnserver-v4.04-9412-rtm-2014.01.15-linux-x64-64bit.tar.gz,
drw------- 2 prashant prashant    4096 Jan  9 08:20 Templates,
drw------- 2 prashant prashant    4096 Jan  9 08:20 Videos,
drwx------ 5 prashant prashant    4096 Jan 22 16:12 vpnserver
```

```
chmod 600 *
chmod 700 vpnserver
chmod 700 vpncmd
```

Comment: open a terminal and run command: 'ls -l' paste output

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Tried and got the edited portion in question.

Comment: it shows that you are not the owner of these directories.

Comment: Prior to this happening, had you run and `sudo chmod` commands?

Comment: Yeah, I did while installing Softether vpn @douggro

Comment: Thanks. Well, I got the coded portion in the question @AvinashRaj

Comment: Ok, please edit your question with that information along with the `chmod` command you ran (if you can remember). Your command set all but the `vpnserver` directory to `600` permissions - read/write only for the owner, which is not desirable.

Comment: Done to the extent I can remember @douggro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you did not use the `-R` recursive command, you can recover from this using

```
cd ~/
chmod 755 *
chmod 644 examples.desktop
chmod 777 Public
chmod 700 vpnserver
chmod 775 softether-vpnserver-v4.04-9412-rtm-2014.01.15-linux-x64-64bit.tar.gz
```

I can't give instructions for the `dwhelper` directory or the `SoftEther-VPN-Server` file as I don't know what the default permissions of those should be. I suspect that 755 will be fine for for both of them.

In the future when using `chmod` be very specific about what file or directory you are changing permissions on. The wildcard `*` will apply it to everything in the specified or current directory. Read `man chmod` for the full list of `chmod` commands and implications of usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem solved. And I definitely going to read man chmod next.